# Can we have a "X days ago" label for sites that passed commitment but haven't entered beta please?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase

The [Gamification proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/gamification) has reached 100% commitment and will go into beta "soon". The proposal page reads:

> This proposal has reached 100% commitment. We are preparing for its launch and expect to create it soon.

It'd be good to at least guess what "soon" means and to do so it'd be good to know when it has reached 100% commitment. Of course I could go to list of committed users at the bottom and reorder it by "most recent" and then find the top one but this doesn't really work because you can still commit after the site reaches 100% commitment and also it's not very convenient.

Can we have that page read something like this

> This proposal has reached 100% commitment ***N days ago***/***yesterday***/***just now***. We are preparing for its launch and expect to create it soon.

so that it's clear when the 100% commitment was reached please?

Comment: Not only did the gamification proposal, there are 6 other proposal that reached 100% commitment and will launch "soon". - A lot of new beta sites.